# Postfix―last message repeated 582 times

Tags: postfix

I a total noob concerned to Mail Server configuration and since today my Mailsystem does not work well anymore and I am searching any kind of help to fix it.

System:

Ubuntu Linux 10.04.3

Postfix Mail Server

Dovecot IMAP / POP3 Server

I am also using webmin.

Errors:

```
postfix/postqueue[28362]: fatal: usage: postqueue -f | postqueue -i queueid | postqueue -p | postqueue -s site
dovecot: imap-login: Can't connect to auth server at default: Permission denied
last message repeated 582 times
```

the `last message repeated` error appears very often. All the lines above are taken from:

```
/var/log/mail.err
```

What could I do to get this fixed? Where should I start searching?

Greetings....

Answer (score 1):

This is the part you should probably be focusing on:

```
imap-login: Can't connect to auth server at default: Permission denied
```

Comment: thank you! Somehow I could solve that problem, looking for that. But what does the »last message repeated 582 times« stand for? Is it a serious error?

Comment: It means it kept trying to connect, kept failing, and logged that error message 582 times.